# Save email template to database when install data Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, setup, installdata

I want create a new template, but not from **Marketing > Email Templates** i want to do it programmatically from my custom extension, the idea is the new template will be saved when `Setup/InstallData.php` runs, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `InstallData.php` file look like this

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Email\Model\TemplateFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * Template factory
     *
     * @var TemplateFactory
     */
    private $templateFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param TemplateFactory $templateFactory
     */
    public function __construct(TemplateFactory $templateFactory)
    {
        $this->templateFactory = $templateFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) 
    {
        $template = $this->templateFactory->create();
        $template->setTemplateCode('your template name here');
        $template->setTemplateText('your template text here');
        $template->setTemplateStyles('your template custom styles here');    
        $template->setTemplateSubject('your subject here');
        $template->setOrigTemplateCode('code of the template you are replacing');
        $template->save();
    }
}
```

Watch out for syntax errors. I didn't test the code.

Comment: where the content .html  i should put? and  what if i dont wan't to replace the existing template?

Comment: you have to add the content you want to be sent via email. And this won't replace a template. Sorry. I chose my words wrong. It will be an alternative to an already existing email.

Comment: the template is saved, but when i tried to send the email, i didnt receive the email, but when i change the email template to default, i received the email